# 'Un uomo dall'esemplare coraggio' vs. 'un uomo di esemplare coraggio'

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> Ogni persona contribuisca al sostegno della famiglia di un uomo dall'esemplare coraggio ed altruismo.

> Ogni persona contribuisca al sostegno della famiglia di un uomo di esemplare coraggio ed altruismo.

La scelta fra `dall'esemplare` e `di esemplare` è questione di stile o, com'è balenato nella mia mente, la prima opzione non è affatto corretta?

Comment: Nel primo caso l'aggettivo dovrebbe seguire, non precedere: *un uomo dal coraggio e altruismo esemplari*.

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers to your question, please consider the option to "accept" an answer by clicking a checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Più giusta o meno giusta non esiste. È questione di stile e sicuramente potrebbe capitare che un autore utilizzi "dall'esemplare" volendo enfatizzare qualcosa, come un altro autore utilizzi sempre "dall'esemplare" per enfatizzare tutt'altro.

In aggiunta anche a me sembrano entrambi complementi di qualità, ma non sono un grande esperto in materia quindi lascerei rispondere a qualcun altro.

Answer (score 0):

Nel primo caso è un complemento di qualità, nel secondo complemento di specificazione. Io direi che la prima è più giusta, volendo mettere l'attenzione sull'uomo.

Comment: Non mi pare che il complemento cambi.

Comment: Sinceramente nemmeno a me, sembrerebbero tutti e due complementi di qualità

Answer (score 0):

Concordo anch'io che sono entrambi complementi di qualità. Cambia solo l'attributo eliso: nel primo caso l'uomo è "caratterizzato" dal coraggio, nel secondo è "dotato" di coraggio. Logicamente sono due frasi equivalenti; la prima versione appartiene ad un registro leggermente più alto, solo per il fatto che viene usata raramente nel linguaggio parlato.